# How to find the most common phrases in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, php, mysqli

I have a table which contains articles on movies. Each article has a title and many of them have common phrases in them.

I would like to do some analysis on the data and extract these common phrases along with a count of their usage.

Here is a simple example:

```
Title
------------------------------------------------
John cannot connect to Asian number
The backup service cannot connect to the client
Mary cannot connect her laptop to the network
```

From this data I would like to be able to extract the following:

```
Phrase                                             Count
-------------------------------------------------- -------
cannot connect                                     3
cannot connect to                                  2
```

My database is in MySQL and I'm using php to code. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your application code to extract "phrases" and store them in a table.  Then do `SELECT ... GROUP BY ...` to generate the counts in question.

No, it is *not* practical to do this entirely in SQL.  SQL is limited in its text parsing ability.